# SMTP Server in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, email, smtp

i am trying to implement an SMTP server using the `net` module in node.js.
The following is a basic SMTP communication between a client and a server.
The problem is that this code doesn't allow me to handle the return code for each command separately. In other words after receiving a response from the server with a return code, i can't this response for which command.

This the code for the SMTP server

```
const net = require('net');

const CRLF = '\r\n';

const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    console.log("Client Connected");

    function writeCommand(c) {
        socket.write(c + CRLF, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error");
                return;
            }
            console.log("SENT: " + c);
        });
    }

    let email = false;
    let emailContent = '';

    socket.on('data', data => {

        if (data.startsWith('EHLO') || data.startsWith('HELO')) {
            writeCommand('250 Welcome');
        } else if (data.startsWith('MAIL FROM:')) {
            writeCommand("250 OK");
        } else if (data.startsWith('RCPT TO:')) {
            writeCommand('250 OK');
        } else if (data.startsWith("DATA")) {
            email = true;
            writeCommand('354 OK');
        } else if (data === ".") {
            writeCommand('250 Message Delivered');
            email = false;
            console.log(emailContent)
        } else if (data === "QUIT") {
            writeCommand("221 Keep In Touch")
        } else {
            if (email) {
                emailContent += data;
                writeCommand("250 OK");
            } else {
                writeCommand("500 Unrecognized command");
            }
        }
    })

    socket.on('error', () => {
        console.log("Error");
    })
})

server.listen(25, () => console.log("SMTP Server Is Running On Port 25..."));
```

This is the code for the SMTP Client

```
const socket = net.createConnection(SERVER.PORT, SERVER.HOST, () => {
    console.log("Connected...");
})
const COMMANDS = [
    `MAIL FROM: <${MAIL.SENDER_ADDRESS}>`,
    `RCPT TO: <${MAIL.RECIPIENT_ADDRESS}>`,
    'DATA',
    'This is the mail content',
    '.'
]
let i = 0;
socket.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log("RECEIVED:", { data: chunk.toString() });
    if (i < COMMANDS.length) {
        writeCommand(COMMANDS[i]);
        i++;
    }
})

writeCommand(`EHLO ${SERVER.HOST}`);
```